# AngularJs manter resultado do $http em cache

Tags: angularjs

Bom pessoal, seguinte, estou montando uma aplicação que envolve muita navegação e visualização de dados. Seria mais ou menos assim:

Existe uma tabela de clientes (+500 cadastrados) com aprox. 35 colunas de dados informativos por clientes. Além disso, existe a view de processos, ordens de serviços, etc.. Todas elas são geradas com base nos clientes.

O fluxo de uso do sistema envolve muita navegação entra essas views. Por exemplo:

> Acessa clientes -> seleciona um deles -> visualiza as ordens de serviço dele -> volta para os clientes -> visualiza outro cliente -> Se entrar nova ordem, acessa a view de ordem de serviço, etc...

Para cada uma dessas views eu faço um `$http` onde pego uma lista de clientes, uma lista de processos, ou uma lista de ordem de serviço, dependendo da `view`.

O `request` é feito com um código simples, através de um factory

```
//factory
getCliente: function() {
    return $http.get("api/func.php?action=get_cliente").then( 
        function(res) { return res.data;},
        function(err) {alert(feedbackError);}
    );
},

//controller
factCliente.getCliente().then(function(res) {
    $scope.detcliente = res;
});
```

Essas listas podem sofrer alteração, ou receber novos dados, mas a frequência com que isso acontece é bem inferior à frequência com que o usuário precisa navegar.

### O problema

A aplicação está começando a ficar com lentidão no momento de exibir as views. Em torno de 1-2s de delay (pois dependendo da `view`, envolve uma combinação de `sql` para obter a lista - Nesta área, não temos mais como mexer).

Não podemos gerar a lista e salvar em um arquivo `.json` (como fazíamos antes) pois alguns dados são sigilosos, então somente o usuário logado pode visualizar.

### A dúvida

O que poderia ser feito para resolver esse problema? Atualmente estou utilizando um `limitTo:50` que ajuda um pouco, mas ele possui algumas limitações, por exemplo: Se a tabela exibe apenas 10 registros e o usuário tentar filtrar ela por um campo de textos, os outros resultados não vão aparecer na tela (pelo menos não como está por enquanto).

Existem algum modo de manter os dados em cache no angularJs para que facilite a performance com o uso do `$http`?

Comment: Camarada, não sei o contexto do teu projeto. Mais o problema está com cara de ser mais backend do que frontend. Vc consegue mensurar isso? Precisa ver se o backend que está lento ou se ao receber os dados o angular está demorando por algum motivo. O fato é que como o volume de dados é grande, vc fez uma boa escolha o usar angular. Porém precisa ver também se está fazendo o uso do framework da forma correta.

Comment: Sim, na verdade eu imagino que seja algo no AngularJs, pois se eu colocar um `limitTo:5` a tabela aparece instantaneamente, porém quando deixo livre ele acaba tendo esse delay. O maior problema é que eu sei que o cliente já tem mais 500-600 clientes para serem cadastrados, pois está migrando o sistema dele. Então vai ficar 'pior'.

Comment: Certo, já pensou em usar scroll-infinito? Veja um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesjones/sqas5wjp/. Se precisar tenho font no github mais simples. Roda com java + rest

Comment: É o que eu tinha em mente. Mas ele criaria o mesmo problema do limitTo, não? Ou seja, se iniciar a exibição com 10 (por exemplo) e eu usar o filtro de busca por texto, ele vai mostrar os demais? Ou mais de 10 resultados?

Comment: Então, depende da forma com que for implementada. Vc pode passar um valor. Inicio=0, Fim=10, na primeira consulta, Inicio=10, Fim=20 na segunda e Inicio=20, Fim=30 na terceira. Assim por diante. E no teu lado backend vc vai usar esses valores de inicio e fim para ir paginando. O que roda no teu backend? Se for java veja: https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/tree/master/scroll-infinito-angular-rest-datafactory

Comment: Porquê não continuar salvando a informação em .json ou Web Sql, e deletar sempre que a aplicação é aberta ou usuário deslogar? Assim, ela continuaria sendo restrita a este usuário.

Comment: O problema disso é que, como é de uso constante, ou seja, tem o fluxo de trabalho da empresa ali, ele ficaria o json enquanto a pessoa estivesse online - Horário comercial. E é isso que desejo evitar, não deixar o json com os dados no servidor. O que seria o WebSql?

Comment: @EmirMarques No momento meu be é em mySql. Acho que vou fazer um filtro para a tabela, com botões de exibição 5 - 10 - 50 - todos e utilizar o limitTo. o Infinite scroll também é interessante, mas nesse caso, como existe muito vai e vem de informação, acho que vai ser a melhor saída.

Comment: Mais qual linguagem faz o link entre o banco de dados e o angular?

Comment: php, com mysql server